# How to take input from std::vector of std::pair in a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdmap

```
int n,a,b,c;
cin >> n;
map<int,vector<pair<int,int>>> mv;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    mv[a].insert(make_pair(b,c));
}
```

I m trying to take input from *`std::vector` of `std::pair`* which is in a `std::map`.Is it possible?

And, how can I iterate through the map?

Comment: [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) takes an iterator to indicate where to insert the new element. Perhaps you meant [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)?

Comment: Could you clarify the problem a bit more? It doesn't make any sense. By saying 'trying to take input from vector pair' what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mv[a].insert(...)` is not the right function call. You need to use `mv[a].push_back(...)`. Remember that `mv[a]` return a reference to the value in the map that corresponds to the key `a`.

If you divide that line in two, it will make more sense.

```
int n,a,b,c;
cin >> n;
map<int,vector<pair<int,int>>> mv;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    vector<pair<int,int>>& v = mv[a];
    v.push_back(make_pair(b,c));
}
```

Comment: Or even `v.emplace_back(b,c);`.